# Custome home page url

Tags: urls

Is it possible to have specific url just for home page?

I have set that recent posts are displayed on home page and I don't want it blank but instead something like *www.myweb.com/home/*
and on other pages/posts I don't want that *home* included.

So *www.myweb.com/other-page/* should not be *www.myweb.com/home/other-page/*

Is it possible to do?

Btw I wouldn't do that if it is not needed, this is just part of bigger issue but one solution is having that specific url for home page.

Comment: So what would be on, in your example, www.myweb.com/?

Comment: nothing, that is not important in my case. Question is just example, that wp is in subfolder and it is not main web on domain

Answer (score 0):

First of all: this is not at all how websites behave. The standard is that you have some kind of homepage on the root URL `/`.

Now WordPress is customizable and I was able to achieve what you want - at least in most ways.

```
// used to generate the link
add_filter('page_link', 'WPSE_1805_page_link', 10, 3);
function WPSE_1805_page_link($link, $post_id, $sample) {
    // if link for any page other than home was requested, return early
    if ($link !== home_url('/'))
        return $link;

    // otherwise, return page link with slug
    return _get_page_link($post_id);
}

// don't redirect /slug to / for homepage
add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'WPSE_1805_redirect_canonical', 10, 2);
function WPSE_1805_redirect_canonical($redirect_url, $requested_url) {
    $home = get_page_link(get_option('page_on_front'));

    // if home was requested, return requested URL
    if ($requested_url === $home)
        return $requested_url;

    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Most necessary functions are within [wp-includes/link-template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/link-template.php) where I found these hooks.

`page_link` is necessary, so `/foo` doesn't get rewritten to `/` just because it is the front page (when creating/getting page links, e.g. via `get_permalink()`).

`redirect_canonical` you need, so when a visitor comes to `/foo`, they do not get redirected to `/`.

---

With this, visitors can still go to `/` and will see the content from the selected static front page (although the canonical link will be set to `/foo`, so search engines should list that link instead).

To disable this, or better said redirect visitors, you can use the following

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'WPSE_1805_template_redirect');
function WPSE_1805_template_redirect() {
    global $wp;

    // get requested URL
    $current_url = home_url( $wp->request );
    // if requested URL is root or root with ending slash
    if ($current_url === home_url('') || $current_url === home_url('/')) {
        wp_redirect( get_page_link(get_option('page_on_front')), 301 );
        exit;
    }
}
```

---

Even with this, you will still have links going to `/`, simply because theme authors may use `home_url('/')` in their code. You could filter that, but my other code would need to be rewritten, because it too uses this function.